# Horizontally paging doesn't work with TabBarController and NavigationBarController

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I've a problem with my UIScollView which doesn't work correctly.

So this is my problem on this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeeCoGm9-b0&feature=youtu.be

And this is the code associate to :

CODE 1 :

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let frameHeight: CGFloat = 100
    let heightOfNewsCell : CGFloat = 100
    var timerForNews = Timer()
    var plugeeNews = ["Plugee permet de partager vos fiches de révision !","Ajoutez à vos favoris les fiches de vos amis !"
        ,"Pourquoi ne pas invitez vos amis a rejoindre Plugee ?","Vous ne savez pas comment utiliser Plugee ? Cliquez ici !"]

    let  newsOfPlugScrollView : UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.isPagingEnabled = true
        sv.backgroundColor = .gray
        return sv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 227, g: 228, b: 231)
        self.navigationItem.title = "News"
        setupMyViews()
        setupNewsScrollView()

    }
    func setupMyViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(newsOfPlugScrollView)

        newsOfPlugScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor,constant : 100).isActive = true
        newsOfPlugScrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        newsOfPlugScrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        newsOfPlugScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: frameHeight).isActive = true
    }

    func setupNewsScrollView() {
        newsOfPlugScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: frameHeight)

        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: frameHeight))
        view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.width, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: frameHeight))
        view1.backgroundColor =  .red
        view2.backgroundColor = .blue
        newsOfPlugScrollView.addSubview(view1)
        newsOfPlugScrollView.addSubview(view2)
        newsOfPlugScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 2, height: frameHeight)
    }
```

I tested this same class (code 1) in an empty project and it works perfectly ( https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=Z0YvNwtYvAc ) . So i supposed the problem cames from the tabBarController code ( But i don't know why ).

This is the tabBarController code :

CODE 2  :

```
 class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var arrayViews : [UIViewController] = [createAViewController(controller: NewsController(), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconeTabBar"))]

        arrayViews.append(createAViewController(controller: HomeController(), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconeTabBar")))
        arrayViews.append(createAViewController(controller: TopController(), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IconeTabBar")))

        viewControllers = arrayViews
        self.selectedIndex = 1
    }

    private func createAViewController(controller : UIViewController, image : UIImage) -> UINavigationController {
        let controller = controller
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        navController.tabBarItem.title = ""
        navController.tabBarItem.image = image
        navController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
        navController.tabBarItem.title = nil
        return navController
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was just this property of my ViewController :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
```

You must set this property to false ( true by default ). 
The description of the documentation explain it :

> The default value of this property is true, which lets container view controllers know that they should adjust the scroll view insets of this view controller’s view to account for screen areas consumed by a status bar, search bar, navigation bar, toolbar, or tab bar. Set this property to false if your view controller implementation manages its own scroll view inset adjustments